# Internet Explorer height: auto on wrapper with clear: both

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I cant find the answer to this question on StackOverflow. I have a site like this:

```
<div id="content">

    ... content....
    <br style="clear: both;" />

</div>
```

The content div automatically fits around the content and has a white background color (That SHOULD happen).

But Internet Explorer doesn't respect `height: auto`, so it doesn't fit with the content.

[My live example is here.](http://52catering.nl/v5/dranken.php) I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I was playing with the css, and when I applied Display: table to the #content div, it worked. I don't know if this is the best way to do it though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your div that looks like this:

```
 <!-- Add an overflow:hidden; css property to this parent div-->
 <div style="...">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="middenbalk">...</div>
    <div id="wrap">..</div>
 </div>
```

Add and overflow:hidden; to make the white background cover all of the content

Comment: This worked, what is the difference with display: table?

Comment: The display:table; attribute is used when you want your div or other html elements to behave like a table, so I wouldn't use it because you might get unexpected behavior. Overflow:hidden; tells the div to match the height of the children's height and width.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've marked your answer as "the answer". It's really weird because without setting overflow:hidden, it worked on my pc in chrome but it didn't work on my laptop in chrome or internet explorer. But this fixed it for all browsers, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set height on body and HTML to 100% in your CSS.

Or you could make the backgound fixed on your body:

CSS

```
body {
    background: url('3.bp.blogspot.com/-AMo1KrsU8yU/UK9SlxEZ_fI/AAAAAAAAF9U/…) no-repeat center center fixed;
{
```

and still set the height to 100% for body and HTML in your CSS.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough but I think I fixed it